# Is this method allowed for centering an object with css?

Tags: css, css-position

Is this way to center an object?
This method creates a accurate center position as well, is there another method to do this?

```
.content {
    width:1200px;
    height:800px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-600px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-400px;
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: simply use margin 0 and auto

Comment: Hi - you might want to add some detail as to the sort of object you wish to center, and why you are looking for an alternative if you already have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

```js
(function() {
  var toggle = true;
  setInterval(function() {
    if (toggle) {
      $("#content").html("Line 1");
    } else {
      $("#content").html("<div>Line 1</div><div>Line 2</div>");
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
  }, 1300);
}());
```

```css
body {
  font: 36px Arial, sans-serif;
}

#container {
  color: white;
  background: #ffbd17;
  width: 400px;
  height: 260px;
}

#content {
  background: #06c;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Centering example:
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    Line 1
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try simply:

```
content{
   margin:50% auto;
   text-align:center;/* if content has text then*/
   /*Your other properties like:width,height,etc*/
}
```

Comment: This is only horizontal alignment. He's also looking for vertical alignment. For vertical check this out: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 0):

yups thats the exact way if you want to center any div on both horizontally and vertically.

Negative margins are exactly half the height and width, which pull the element back into perfect center. Only works with elements of a fixed height/width.

or you can use

```
.content{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:200px;
}
```

or you can use it in inline coding if you dont have specific measure

```
<div style="display:table;height:300px;text-align:center;">
<div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
<!–content–>
</div>
</div>
```

For further help, go this [tutorial](http://www.noobcube.com/tutorials/html-css/horizontal-and-vertical-centering-using-css-a-beginners-guide-/), its the good and quite helpful in understanding in centering the elements horizontally and vertically.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this using `display: table-cell;`. This way it gets centered vertically and horizontally and it *does not* depend of the height of the element you want to display.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        I'm centered.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSSS**

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/Gyq4t/

**Note**

This works fine in every modern browser. I does not work in IE7.